imePadding in ModalBottomSheet in Compose on API level 29 and lower
I have the following code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun FilterScreen(
    component: SearchComponent,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit
) {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = true
    )
    
    val countriesIS = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val filterState by component.filterState.collectAsState()

    var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = {
            showBottomSheet = false
            onDismiss()
        },
        sheetState = sheetState,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 50.dp, topStart = 50.dp),
        containerColor = Color.White
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .imePadding()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        ) {
            AutocompleteTextEdit(
                labelText = Strings.getString("citizenship"),
                interactionSource = countriesIS,
                text = filterState.countriesString,
                items = component.countries,
                onValueChange = { newText -> component.onEvent(SearchEvents.UpdateCountries(newText)) },
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.requiredHeight(12.dp))
            Row {
                DefaultButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .requiredHeight(mainButtonHeight)
                        .padding(start = mainSideMargin, end = halfMainSideMargin),
                    text = Strings.getString("clear"),
                    isFilled = false,
                ) {
                    component.onEvent(SearchEvents.ClearFilter)
                }
                DefaultButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .requiredHeight(mainButtonHeight)
                        .padding(start = 8.dp, end = mainSideMargin),
                    text = Strings.getString("search"),
                ) {
                    component.onEvent(SearchEvents.ApplyFilter)
                }
            }
            Spacer(Modifier
                .requiredHeight(250.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

I included on Autocomplete composable in code, but really I have a lot of these Autocomplete fields so my bottom sheet dialog takes more than full screen.
I have a problem of determining ime paddings in Compose on platforms with SDK29 or lower in ModalBottomSheet.
I have a lot of these Autocomplete fields so my bottom sheet dialog takes full screen.
On SDK higher than 29 there's no problem. When keyboard appears my dialog is scrollable so I can see it fully.
But on platforms lower than 29 keyboard covers the lower part of the sheet.
Yet on 29- no recomposition happens.
I added adjustResize to activity in Manifest. And it helps on usual screens but not in ModalBottomSheet.
Also I made some breakpoints in code and on platforms 30+ recomposition happens on keyboard show/hide.

You should change window mode in manifest file for the activity hosting composables like below
<activity
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
..>

This will make all screens fully scrollable when keyboard is open.
It also applies to all the bottomsheet we open so your issue will be solved.

I've done it of course. It makes normal scroll on non-modal screens but doesn't work in ModalBottomSheet.

Same here, the keyboard still push the screen up, but not the ModalBottomSheet on API 29 and below
